# Remove all elements that are not inside a specific command

Tags: boxes

I want to typese a document so that all words/elements that are not inside a certain command are swallowed.

I.e. I want the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{...}
...
\begin{document}
hide \mycommand{show} hide
\end{document}
```

to compile as
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the pseudo-environment `\hidemost`...`\endhidemost`.  You can remove the asterisks from the `\mycommand` definition if you don't want them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{*#1*}
\def\z{F}
\tokcycleenvironment\hidemost
{}
{\tctestifcon{\if T\z}{\addcytoks{{##1}}}{\processtoks{##1}}\gdef\z{F}}
{\ifx\mycommand##1\addcytoks{##1}\gdef\z{T}\fi}
{}
\begin{document}
\hidemost
hide \mycommand{show} hide and {test}

much other {and inside a group \mycommand{other stuff}}

\section{Blah}

and finally \mycommand{last things} and we are done
\endhidemost
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I am not familier with tokcycle. Is the cruxial for this solution?

Comment: @sheß Absolutely crucial.  It allows one to process through a token list and set up tests and decision making based on the particular tokens that arise.

Comment: @sheß See documentation and examples file at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was trying to use this together with latexdiff to create a one separate document of all additions and one of all deletions. The complexity (and messiness) of the latexdiff-generated tex files makes this difficult and I decided for a manual approach instead. Thanks for the help anyways.